# DEPRECATION WARNING: :confirm option is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.0. Use ':data => { :confirm => 'Text' }' instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've upgraded my rails sample app from version 3.1 to version 3.2.6. Unfortunately, I have the following deprecation warning.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: :confirm option is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.0. Use ':data => { :confirm => 'Text' }' instead. (called from _app_views_shared__feed_item_html_erb___1282539180373198927_70193136005180 at /Users/Bart/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb:27)
```

Looking forward to tackle this issue.

Best regards

Comment: So .. Why not just do what it says to do? Or ignore it for now; but realize it could disappear eventually. -1 as there is no question, or issue, here.

Comment: pst is exactly right.  Upgrade pains happen.  Now, if you're having issues fixing this, then say what you've tried, and give an idea where you want to end up.  "Looking forward to tackle this issue" doesn't say how you want to tackle it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way this warning reads, you need to edit line 27 of your shared/_feed_item.html.erb view. It is a simple change of

```
link_to 'Do Something', some_path, :confirm => 'Text'
```

to

```
link_to 'Do Something', some_path, :data => { :confirm => 'Text' }
```

or the newer Rails 1.9 syntax:

```
link_to 'Do Something', some_path, data: { confirm: 'Do you really want to do something?' }
```

Here is a link to the [Rails commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fc092a9cba5fceec38358072e50e09250cf58840) and the [Rails team's discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6613#issuecomment-6458648) where the deprecation occurred.

Comment: I have edited line 27 as specified by scarver2 

<%= link_to "delete", feed_item,:method => :delete, 
 :data => { :confirm => 'are you sure' }, 
 :title => "feed_item.content"%>

This simple change makes my tests pass.